# UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure Color Change

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7, uiimage, mkannotationview

I have changed the image of `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` to the image below but the problem is that the image becomes in blue color. Where would be my issue?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
*infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

[infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carcar.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Last update: Solved with last infoButton.frame.

```
    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage *carImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carcar.png"];

    if ([carImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)])
    {
        carImage = [carImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    }

    [infoButton setImage:carImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);

    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
```

Comment: What is the width and height of carcar.png?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina it is 100x100

Comment: Try reducing it to 32 x 32.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Unfortunately it is not showing it.

Comment: Are you using UIButtonTypeCustom and did you set infoButton.frame to 0, 0, 32, 32?

Comment: Thanks it works after I have wrote `infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);` If you want answer and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom button type:

```
infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

If you want to add your own image, you should always use this method. The other types are for pre-defined buttons (like info, add contact, etc.)

Comment: Thanks but I got nothing it is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and resolved it as follows (using your code):

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[infoButton setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIImage *carImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"carcar.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

[infoButton setBackgroundImage:carImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like iOS 7 is treating your image as a template.  Try replacing

```
[infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"carcar.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

with

```
UIImage *carImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carcar.png"];
if ([carImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)])
{
    carImage = [carImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}

[infoButton setImage:carImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Gosh.  What happens if you do add in Antonio's suggestion?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: What happens if you use `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` *and* set the image's rendering mode?

Comment: I have used @AntonioMG answer `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` but still it is not showing anything.

Comment: Have you tried both at once?  Using `UIButtonTypeCustom` *and* setting the image's rendering mode?

Comment: I have update my question with my last code could you check please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different button type and set it's frame.

You see nothing because the frame of your button is zero (for UIButtonTypeCustom). So, in order to fix your problem you can:

```
infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// set image
[infoButton setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// More elegant then setting hardcoded frame
[infoButton sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
static NSString * const identifier = @"MyCustomAnnotation";

    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView1 dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView)
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    //left image view
    UIImageView *imageIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"]];
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageIcon;

    //right button with image
    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [infoButton setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIImage *carImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [infoButton setBackgroundImage:carImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_image.png"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
```